# Displaying large networks with cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

I'm trying to use cytoscape.js to display large networks with hundreds of nodes. However, cytoscape.js seems to always want to constrain everything to the viewport, which can be problematic if there are too many nodes crowding up the viewport. I'm using the "arbor" layout and during the force-directed simulation the nodes don't seem to exit the viewport's initial boundaries, even if I zoom out at initialization. Setting arbor's fit option to *false* also doesn't seem to do anything. What is the preferred way to go about displaying large networks in cytoscape.js?

Answer (score 0):

There are other layouts you can use.  I'll look into the issue with arbor, though https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/307

Comment: To clarify, what I meant by fit=false not doing anything is that arbor would still try to fit the network to the initial dimensions of the viewport. This leads to some strange behaviour when zooming out at initialization and seeing the arbor simulation taking place in a small box that's only a portion of the current view. Is there a way around this "bounding" problem? 

When creating a Cytoscape instance with an initial zoom and setting arbor's fit to false, the view is not changed to fit the viewport, so fit is working correctly in that sense.